# What are the long-term health impact of dehydration before bodybuilding competitions?

Tags: water, sports

Bodybuilders often dehydrate themselves before competitions. What are the long-term health impact of dehydration before bodybuilding competitions?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.